# Escape double quotes and single quotes in Jenkins pipeline script

Tags: powershell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have one powershell command inside that both Double quotes and single quotes are present and it's needed for sure in order to make the command execute successfully in dos prompt. I am not sure how to make it escape in pipeline script.

```
bat "powershell -Command "(Get-Content "${Physical_FolderLoc}\\${Stord_Process_Name}.txt") | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace [RegEx]::Escape('E:\\config'), 'I:\\config' } | Set-Content "${Physical_FolderLoc}\\${Stord_Process_Name}.txt" " "
```

In the above command you can see the second last " is ending quote for Get Content and last one is for bat command.
I tried the above command with triple slash but getting groovy error.

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: _ for class: groovy.lang.Binding
at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: What do you use "bat"? Jenkins pipelines also support powershell.

Comment: okay. Yeah I use bat, But the Jenkins parameter variable might not resolve with base64 encode no matter if I use bat or powershell command.

Comment: @elou Hi Elou. I had gone through your post regarding the powershell command incorporation in Jenkin's pipeline, can you please help me to pass the above powershell command into jenkins pipeline. The double quote " before Get-Content is needed for sure. I am passing the command in bat " ".

Comment: @Vasiliki Siakka please help me to resolve the above powershell command. I have gone through your earlier post regarding the No such property: _ for class: groovy.lang.Binding, bcoz I am getting the same error for the above powershell command may be due to the double quote escape.

Answer (score 0):

Change each internal double quoted string, eg:

```
"${Physical_FolderLoc}\\${Stord_Process_Name}.txt"
```

to:

```
('{0}\\{1}.txt' -f $Physical_FolderLoc, $Stord_Process_Name)
```

Comment: can you please address the complete command, it will be very much helpful.

Comment: please take a moment and address the command for once so that in future I can take care of any sort of issues like this.

Comment: I tried as per your recommendation, it's throwing error. groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: _ for class: groovy.lang.Binding
 at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:270)
 at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$7.call(Checker.java:353)

Comment: I'm passing exactly:  bat "powershell.exe -Command \"(Get-Content ('{0}\\{1}.txt' -f $Physical_FolderLoc, $Stord_Process_Name)) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace [RegEx]::Escape('E:\\config'), 'I:\\config' } | Set-Content ('{0}\\{1}.txt' -f $Physical_FolderLoc, $Stord_Process_Name)\" "

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact issue why the command was not escaping. There is a stand alone **$** symbol in the powershell command which is also a system character for groovy, so that need to be escaped as well.(The **$** character which is after **ForEach-Object {**). It's now prefixed with \, so escaped.

Now the complete command is :

```
bat "powershell -Command \"(Get-Content ${Physical_FolderLoc}\\${Stord_Process_Name}.txt) | ForEach-Object { \$_ -replace [RegEx]::Escape('E:\\config'), 'I:\\config' } | Set-Content ${Physical_FolderLoc}\\${Stord_Process_Name}.txt\" "
```

Though no one had tried to help much, but still thanks a lot for the suggestion.